# What is the easy way to display menu after clicked on Icon in mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have to display a menu on a mobile device. When the user clicked on menubar icon than menu will display with the full background color on screen and cross sign will appear. after clicked on cross sign menu will close. I tried some code which is not working properly. I need easy and best answer. Would help me in this?

```js
$(function() {
  var menuVisible = false;
  $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
  $("#main-list").slideDown();
  //manu bar will hide after clicked 
  $('#menuBtn').css({'display': 'none'});
  
  //cross sign will displya after clicked menu bar
  $('#menu-close-sign').css({'display': 'block' });
  $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
  $("#main-list").show();
  $('#menu-close-sign').show();
  $('#menu').css({'background-color': '#F4FAFF', 'height': '100%'});
  $('#menuBtn').hide();
  });
  
  $('#menu-close-sign').click(function() {
  $("#main-list").hide();
  $('#menu-close-sign').hide();
  $('#menuBtn').show();
  $('#menu').css({'background-color': '#fff', 'height': '50px'});
  // $(".right_side").slideUp();
  });
  
  if (menuVisible) {
  $('.right_side').css({'display': 'none' });
  menuVisible = false;
  return;
  }
  $('.right_side').css({'display': 'block'});
  $('.menu').css({'background-color': '#F4FAFF', 'height': '100%'});
  menuVisible = true;
  });
  });
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
  #menu
  {
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 70px;
   z-index: 999;
   webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  }
  .menu-section
  {
   padding: 0 30px;
  }
  .menu-left-side
  {
   float: left;
  }

  .icon-bar-menu, #menu-close-sign
  {
  display: none;
  }
  .menu-right-side
  {
   float: right;
   margin: 22px;
  }

  ul#main-list{
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  }

  ul#main-list li{
   float: left;
   margin: 0 20px;
  }

  ul#main-list li a{
   color: #212F3D;

  }

  ul#main-list li a:hover
  {
   color: #ffb902;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-left-side
  {
  float:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

  .icon-bar-menu
  {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 9px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  }
  .icon-bar-menu i{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  }

  .menu-right-side
  {
  margin:20px 0;
  }
  ul#main-list
  {
  padding:0;
  }

  ul#main-list li, .menu-right-side
  {
  float:none;
  }
  ul#main-list li
  {
  margin:20px 0;
  }
  #menu
  {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #64d0e7 !important;
  }

  ul#main-list li a
  {
  color:#000;
  }
  #menu-close-sign
  {
  display:none;
  }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--menu-->
  <div id="menu">
  <div class="menu-section">
  <div class="menu-left-side">

   <div class="logo-section">
   <a href="index.php"><h2>logo</h2></a>
   </div><!--logo-section-->

  </div><!--menu-left-side-->

  <div class="menu-right-side">
  <div class="icon-bar-menu">
  <span id="menuBtn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span id="menu-close-sign"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </div>
   <ul id="main-list">
    <li> <a href="index.php">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.php">news</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.php">contact</a></li>
   </ul><!--main-list-->

  </div><!--menu-right-side-->
  </div><!--menu-section-->
  </div><!--menu-->
```

Comment: You want an easy way to make an hamburger menu? Have you tried bootstrap? It is the easier way for sure.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Andre, I know bootstrap but I don't want to use it. Is there any way to reduce my script? and also use the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your Javascript if you separate the menu icon from the navigation div. On clicking the menu icon, the entire navigation div will show/hide. You can then use media queries to show/hide the mobile icon depending on the screen size.

You will need to tweak the CSS in order to get the close icon in the same position as the menu icon, but that should be fairly easy.

https://codepen.io/cassyj122/pen/NpOXbV

HTML

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!--menu-->
  <span id="menuBtn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-section">
      <div class="menu-left-side">
        <div class="logo-section">
          <a href="index.php"><h2>logo</h2></a>
        </div>
        <!--logo-section-->
      </div>
      <!--menu-left-side-->
      <div class="menu-right-side">
        <div class="icon-bar-menu">
          <span id="menu-close-sign"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <ul id="main-list">
          <li> <a href="index.php">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.php">services</a></li>
          <li><a href="news.php">news</a></li>
          <li><a href="contactus.php">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--main-list-->

      </div>
      <!--menu-right-side-->
    </div>
    <!--menu-section-->
  </div>
  <!--menu-->
</div>

#menu {
  background-color: #64d0e7;
  width: 100%;
}

#menuBtn {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

#menu-close-sign {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

CSS

```
#menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 999;
  webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.menu-section {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.menu-left-side {
  float: left;
}

.menu-right-side {
  float: right;
  margin: 22px;
}

ul#main-list {
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul#main-list li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

ul#main-list li a {
  color: #212F3D;
}

ul#main-list li a:hover {
  color: #ffb902;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #menuBtn {
    display: block;
  }
  #menu-close-sign {
    display: block;
  }
  #menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-left-side {
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .icon-bar-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 9px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
  .icon-bar-menu i {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #000;
  }
  .menu-right-side {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  ul#main-list {
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul#main-list li,
  .menu-right-side {
    float: none;
  }
  ul#main-list li {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  #menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #64d0e7 !important;
  }
  ul#main-list li a {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
    $('#menu').show();
  });
  $('#menu-close-sign').click(function() {
    $('#menu').hide();
  });

});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 600) {
    $('#menu').show();
  } else {
    $('#menu').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Cassandra, 1) Why you used class menuBtn outside of id menu? 2) If I used your script then how can I used the dropdown menu. I mean I am talking about the script?